# Дублирование данных из database

Tags: база-данных, ios, swift, firebase

Мое приложение работает на **collectionView** внутри **tableView**. **collectionView** работает в горизонтальном отображении для скрола фотографий, **tableView** работает для отображений постов для скрола вертикально. Так же у меня встроен индикатор количества отображаемых изображений в каждом из постов. В одном посте может содержаться до 5 фотографий, например:

**1ый пост** - 2 фотографии (яблоко, апельсин), отображает эти 2 фотографии и скролить можно 2 фотографии

**2ой пост** - 3 фотографии (банан, ананас, груша), отображает эти 3 фотографии и скролить можно 3 фотографии

**3ий пост** - 4 фотографии (гранат, абрикос, слива, киви), отображает эти 4 фотографии и скролить можно 4 фотографии

**4ый пост** - 5 фотографий (изюм, дыня, арбуз, огурец, помидор), но 4ый пост почему то отображает изображения из 1ого поста, т.е. (яблоко, апельсин), но в индикации изображений показывает 5 фотографий, но листать я могу только до 2ух фотографий и при чем там отображаются (яблоки, апельсин). Так же при скролле на **1ом посте,** скролл автоматически происходит и на **4ом посте**, что тоже не понятно почему...

Это может быть проблема с **database** или это уже проблема с кодом?

Как смог описал проблему, надеюсь она понятно написана, если что-то не понятно, я всегда готов дописать вопрос или если нужно то добавить код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в переиспользовании ячеек. Нужно попробовать в prepsreforreuse ячейки релоадить collectionView.

Также думаю и для ячеек collectionView нужно обнулять данные при перемспользовании, чтобы не менялись картинки при подгрузке, а появлялись.

Comment: С prepsreforreuse разобрался, а можете примерно подсказать как в ячейках обнулить данные на примитивном примере?